# CKeditor 4x User Guide

Tags: ckeditor

I know this is not the right website to ask for this but I couldn't find an appropriate one among the StackExchange network.

So my question is pretty simple. Where can I find a guide that has detailed explanations of all buttons (on toolbar) of the CKEditor? (I am writing a documentation for a website and i want to find a guide to refer to)

I 've been trying to find something all day but with no luck. If anyone could share a link please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] all buttons (on toolbar) of the CKEditor?

There are so many plugins and custom builds of CKEditor so there's no such thing like "all buttons". You can browse the [official plugin repo](http://ckeditor.com/addons/plugins/all) for brief descriptions of each plugin.

Also the official [documentation website](http://docs.cksource.com/Main_Page) may help you.